# Do I need a flash for trekking/travelling with my D500?

Tags: nikon, dslr, hotshoe-flash, travel

I currently have a dilemma. I use a Nikon D500, which has no built in flash, and was wondering whether it is worth buying a lightweight one to bring with me trekking this coming summer.

The reason I ask is predominately I use it for wildlife and macro but while trekking this tends to go to landscapes and close (non-macro) wildlife - as I travel light.

On my previous two trips I used my D5200 (before upgrading) where I used the flash on the odd occasion for touristy photos of my travel companion etc.

The idea of a flash then was no issue as there was one built in, so it didn't cross my mind, but now I can't seem to make my mind up so would welcome and experienced opinions and a discussion!

If the decision comes to buying a flash it would either be the SB300/500 or the Kenro Mini Flash.

Best 
Kieran

Comment: Only you can really decide this - you're the only person who can weigh up (pun vaguely intentional) the additional cost of carrying a flash around versus the benefit _it will give you_.

Comment: Completely agree that it is only me that can decide - hoping someone whos had a similar dilemma can offer some advice!

Predominately I can't see me using it and might be better with a mini tripod but I am not sure - hence wanting the discussion.

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Exchange isn't a discussion platform - [it's all about the questions and answers to those questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour), and nobody here can answer the question for you. As you've got reputation elsewhere in the network, I think you should be able to [hop into chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography-chat) which is more suited for discussions.

Comment: I had no idea there was a chat system! Many thanks.

Comment: You wont know you need it until you find your self in place where you think "i wish i could fill in the shadows of the scene i am photographing or photograph that Buddha statue in low light"

Comment: @KieranSQ The question might be a bit more answerable if you would give more details abut the situations where you have found flash helpful in the past. "Touristy photos of my travel companion" is not very specific. It could be anything from a midday snapshot outdoors in bright light (where a fill flash might be nice, but often other techniques can accomplish the same thing) to an image of the scene in, or in front of, a dark restaurant at night.